# how can I change what the command "apt-get update" looks for when executing the update?

Tags: debian, apt

Forgive my incompetence I am still new to  GNU/Linux.
I use Debian wheezy.

When I type `apt-get update`

I get this at the end

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

My question is, how would I edit (I'm guessing what apt looks at) to ignore the things that failed to update.. or to remove them completely so I don't get that message anymore.

EDIT:

The only thing I see in sources.list is

```
deb ftp.sun.ac.za/debian wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src ftp.sun.ac.za/debian wheezy main contrib non-free
deb security.debian.org wheezy/updates contrib non-free main
deb-src security.debian.org wheezy/updates contrib non-free maim
```

and that's it. Should I delete one of these? I looked inside `sources.list.d` as well and that came up empty

2nd EDIT:

The output of `apt-cache policy` is

```
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-webupd8team-java,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Oracle Java (JDK) 6 / 7 / 8 Installer PPA,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/non-free Translation-en
 500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/contrib Translation-en
 500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=7.0,o=Debian,a=stable,n=wheezy,l=Debian-Security,c=main
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/non-free amd64 Packages
     release v=7.0,o=Debian,a=stable,n=wheezy,l=Debian-Security,c=non-free
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/contrib amd64 Packages
     release v=7.0,o=Debian,a=stable,n=wheezy,l=Debian-Security,c=contrib
     origin security.debian.org
 500 ftp://ftp.sun.ac.za/debian/ wheezy/non-free Translation-en
 500 ftp://ftp.sun.ac.za/debian/ wheezy/main Translation-en
 500 ftp://ftp.sun.ac.za/debian/ wheezy/contrib Translation-en
 500 ftp://ftp.sun.ac.za/debian/ wheezy/non-free amd64 Packages
     release v=7.4,o=Debian,a=stable,n=wheezy,l=Debian,c=non-free
     origin ftp.sun.ac.za
 500 ftp://ftp.sun.ac.za/debian/ wheezy/contrib amd64 Packages
     release v=7.4,o=Debian,a=stable,n=wheezy,l=Debian,c=contrib
     origin ftp.sun.ac.za
 500 ftp://ftp.sun.ac.za/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
     release v=7.4,o=Debian,a=stable,n=wheezy,l=Debian,c=main
     origin ftp.sun.ac.za
Pinned packages:
```

**3rd and final EDIT:**
after entering `grep -Ri launchpad *` I was able to look at what the results I got back were and proceeded to enter `nano sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list` and delete everything that was there. I then proceeded to also enter 
`nano sources.list.d/webupd8team-java-wheezy.list` and deleted everything that was there as well. 
Then I did `apt-get update` and everything is back to normal .

Comment: I see `ppa.launchpad.net` in your output of `apt-cache policy`. That suggests that this is mentioned somewhere. Are you sure there is nothing in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`? If so, this seems a little strange.

Comment: As @Braiam, suggests, try doing a grep. I'd actually suggest just a `grep -Ri launchpad /etc/apt/`. Or even `cd /etc/apt`. And then `grep -Ri launchpad *`.

Comment: Hi. Yes, you are correct. When I type `cd /etc/apt/` and `grep -Ri launchpad *` it shows `sources.list.d/webupd8team-java-wheezy.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu wheezy main
sources.list.d/webupd8team-java-wheezy.list:deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu wheezy main
sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list:deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
`

which is exactly what's causing this.

How would I go about removing it?

Comment: Just put a `#` in front of the relevant lines. This will comment out those lines so apt won't see it, as mentioned in my answer. Or you could just remove the files.

Comment: ^ I understand that part, but where do I do this (as mentioned, I'm pretty new, sorry.)? How do I get to the file.

EDIT: I got it. I used `nano sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list` and I found where they're located. Thank you so much guys.

Comment: Yes, you need to use an editor. Other good choices are emacs and jed. There are tons of others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most of the time, a source line will be in the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`, so you should edit that. However, if you don't find it there, look at files inside the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. As far as I know, a source line *must* be on of those two places. Reference: `man sources.list`.

Putting the comment character `#` in front of any source line should be enough for apt to ignore it.

Comment: I did as you suggested. The only thing I see in sources.list is 

deb ftp://ftp.sun.ac.za/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src ftp://ftp.sun.ac.za/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates contrib non-free main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates contrib non-free main

and thats it. Should I delete one of these? I looked inside sources.list.d as well and that came up empty.

Comment: Ok. Add those into the question, not as a comment. It is pertinent to the question. The sources line you reference *must* be in one of the places I mentioned, as far as I know. See `man sources.list`. Are you still seeing that error when you run `apt-get update`? Please also post the output of `apt-cache policy` in your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There **should be** a line with launchpad somewhere. This should show where:

```
grep -Ri launchpad /etc/apt/sources.list*
```

Could be also that you have configured a personalized path for sources.lists:

```
grep -R Dir /etc/apt/apt.conf*
```

Find it and remove it.